# Voice recognition and localization?

Tags: android, localization, google-translate, voice-recognition

Does anyone have experience with java voice recognition and localization?

I'm thinking to build an android application, with some basic voice recognition options, but I want to implement localization for that based on some translate tool, maybe Google translate, and users can update his "dictionary" with new languages from remote dictionary...this project is in first phase, and I'm still brainstorming, so does anyone have some experience or is something like that even possible?

Comment: You might want to do the recognition server-side, like Google does.  The phones do not have a ton of horsepower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use Android's built-in speech recognition? It's REALLY easy (you just set up an `Intent` then catch it when it returns) and the results are surprisingly good.

[android.speech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html)

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but this will allow you to specify the language to recognize.